# Is $f(n)= n - \sum_{p\leq n} \log(p)$ a function of $\operatorname{O}(n^{\frac{1}{2}})$?

Tags: number-theory

Is $$f(n)= n - \sum_{\text{p is prime},\ p\leq n} \log(p)$$ a function of $\operatorname{O}(n^{\frac{1}{2}})$?

I have written a Matlab program and it gave me the bellow plot that the $x$-axis is $n$ and $y$-axis is $f(n)$.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good guess, but it turns out not to be correct. The function $\theta(n) = \sum_{p\le n} \log p$ (where the sum runs only over primes) is a well-studied function in the context of the prime number theorem in analytic number theory. Littlewood proved, in 1914, that $n-\theta(n)$ is infinitely often greater than a constant times $n^{1/2}\log\log\log n$ (and so is $\theta(n)-n$). In particular, $n-\theta(n)$ is not $O(n^{1/2})$.

On the other hand, we expect (but can't prove) that $n-\theta(n)$ is indeed $O(n^{1/2}(\log n)^2)$. In fact, that assertion is *equivalent* to the Riemann hypothesis!

Comment: thanks a lot for your question. is this easy to prove that $n-\theta(n)$ is $\operatorname{O}(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$?

Comment: That's also equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis, as it turns out. We don't even know that $n-\theta(n)$ is $O(n^{0.9999})$. (We do know that it is $O(n/(\log n)^A)$ for any fixed $A>0$.) Of course, data like yours is a big part of the reason we believe the Riemann hypothesis, even if we can't yet prove it.